# Using data caching and session variables in shared hosting servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, shared-hosting

I have a doubt in mind, if is it a bad practice to use lots of data caching and session variables in shared hosting environments? By shared hosting I mean hosting on servers with less RAM and all. Because what will happen when cache will get huge enough to blow out the memory?

Gaurav

Comment: If you are down voting something then please provide some reason to do this so that I can keep that in mind in future while asking. Thanks

Comment: It is definitively bad idea to cache lots of data if you have less memory. It is same as you ask is it good idea to try fill 1L bottle with 2L water.

Comment: How much RAM, how many simultaneous session, how many data per session. Can you persist session more than 15min inactive etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will depend very much on the server configuration you are hosting your application into. First things first, don't worry for blowing out the memory of you are on shared hosting. Your provider will shut down your application much before the memory usage grows larger than a predefined threshold.

Concerning session, there are a couple of things to consider. The session state mode and the number of nodes your application runs on. For example if you are using the default in-memory session state and running your application on multiple servers (webfarm) then each node will have its own session data in memory. That's dangerous because let's suppose that the user performs its first request on node A and some data is stored in session and the second request is served by node B. Now since the session was stored in the memory of node A, the second request will fail because it won't be able to find the session data. In this case you should consider using an out-of-process session storage mode.

As far as caching is concerned, if you want to optimize it, it is recommended to use a dedicated cache server(s) and not store it in the memory of the web servers.